# Access to fetch blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am getting this error when trying to fetch REST API from Amazon Web Services in script defined html file:

```
Access to fetch at '$(url)' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

script

```
   let body = { token: params.token};
      const response = await fetch(
        url,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
          headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" },
        }
      );
      console.log(response);
      const myJson = await response.json();
      console.log("response-->", myJson);
      if (myJson.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("failed");
        return;
      }
      console.log("success");
        return; 
      }
```

```
Running into CORS error 

API is deployed with below CORS configurations:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpM6h.png)

Comment: Putting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in a request is useless, since it's a response header. Besides, have you configured CORS on your server? If not, find a good CORS middleware for your backend language, and configure CORS to allow trusted clients. But never allow the `null` origin, as doing so is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Once you'r done with [Cors Console Enable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) (i see that you already done it on the image).

You need to follow [this stepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) to setup lambda.

And on your function include headers and response in this way:

```
const headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST'}
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers:headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ token: params.token})
};
return response;
```

so in your fetch you could call it directly and not await it like this:

```
fetch(...).then((response) => {
  return response.json();                
})
```